# How to override Backbone Collection remove method and then call parent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm following recommendations from posts on SO and elsewhere, but can't get this to work.

I want to override the remove function on all Backbone Collections to fire a 'removed' event after all models have been removed.

I've tried this:  [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RSp4e/)

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove = function(models, options){
    console.log('removing');
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove.call(this, models, options);
    this.trigger('removed', models);    
};

var MyColl = Backbone.Collection.extend({ });
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

var myColl = new MyColl();
var myModel = new MyModel();

myColl.add(myModel);
myColl.remove(myModel);
```

...but it appears to call itself recursively and never fires the parent (base) remove method.

How can I correctly override the remove method and call the base method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite method is using Underscore's `wrap()`, especially since Underscore is available by default in Backbone.  I personally enjoy using `wrap()` because it makes clear in plain English what is happening, like so:

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove = _.wrap(
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove,
    function(original_remove, models, options) {
        // Capture original function arguments
        var original_args = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0, 1);

        // Before
        console.log('removing');

        // Call original function with original arguments
        original_remove.apply(this, original_args);

        // After
        this.trigger('removed', models);
    });
```

The only caveat is the `Array.prototype.splice` call, which strips off the first parameter (that Underscore sets to the original function). However, this allows us to use `apply()` with the original arguments, which is a bit more flexible than `call()` since it handles any number of arguments without having to name them explicitly.

Note the use of `Array.prototype.splice` rather than `arguments.splice()`, which is necessary as `arguments` is not a full Javascript Array type and does not carry the splice method in its own prototype.

Answer (score 3):

You're overridding `remove` then calling `remove` on Backbones Collection prototype, so it will call its self.

Instead you should override it in your implementation:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  remove: function(models, options) {
    // Do your stuff
    // ..

    // Call the parent
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove.call(this, models, options)
  }
});
```

You could then of course extend `MyCollection` instead of `Backbone.Collection` to inherit this functionality in other controllers.

An [updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RSp4e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your overwriting the prototype, so when you invoke it, it will keep recursing.
You either need to create a new base collection that gets extended, or push the functionality into your existing extension -- depending on how reusable you want to make it.

```
var MyBaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    remove: function(models, options){
        console.log('removing');
        Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove.call(this, models, options);
        this.trigger('removed', models);    
    }
});

var MyColl = MyBaseCollection.extend({ });
```

or add that into MyColl directly.

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this :

```
var remove = Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove;
Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove = function(models, options){
    console.log('removing');
    remove.call(this, models, options);
    this.trigger('removed', models);    
};
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/RSp4e/2/)